# how to blink a LED without using a sleep?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I am using motion sensor when the motion sensor is detected I wan to turn ON the LED and buzzer at the same time. The buzzer which I am using is a passive buzzer.
How can I Turn ON LED and buzzer at the same time when motion sensor detect without using sleep().

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT) # LED PIN
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT) # buzzer PIN

def TURN_ON():          
    GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.HIGH)
    print("LED ON and BUZZER ON")    
    sleep(5)
    GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.LOW)
    print("LED OFF and BUZZER OFF")
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about why using sleep() is undesirable for your use case?

Comment: @JohnCarter Because sleep() blocks the program while it is running. and it becomes difficult to turn ON the passive buzzer along with LED at the same time.

Comment: Describe your led as GPIO LED in the device tree, and set up blinking trigger. You won’t need even a single line of code to execute something like that. If you need to control that, you may use sysfs for LED framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your environment supports threading, but it probably does.

This article is a great [introduction to threading in python](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/).

Here is a really quick and dirty example of what you are trying to do:

```
def led_on():
    GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)

def buzz_on():
    GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.HIGH)

def delay():
    sleep(5)


def main():
    led_thread = threading.Thread(target=led_on)
    buzz_thread = theading.Thread(target=buzz_on)
    delay_thread = threading.Threading(target=delay)

    all_threads = [led_thread, buzz_thread, delay_thread]

    for thread in all_threads:
        thread.start()

    # at this point, all three functions will be running parallel

    for thread in all_threads:
        thread.join()

    # at this point, we have waited for all three threads to complete
    # the sleep 5 should be the longest running one
```

The above is a *very simplistic* example of how to accomplish your question.  There are many ways it can be improved.  For instance, you can pass parameters/args to the thread constructor and those could be used to set the pin # (avoiding the need for two functions for _on).

This should put you on the right track.